# flashloan-arbitrage: ENS error

Tags: ethers.js, arbitrage

I am trying to write a flashloan trading arbitrage bot as my first project but I keep on hitting the same error and I can not seem to fix it. Can anyone help me? My code's repo is here: https://github.com/SquilliamX/Trading-bot

this is the error that is keeps appearing when I run "node bot.js". The readMe will explain how to deploy it so you can see the error yourself as well. Can anyone explain why this error keeps appearing whenever I run node bot.js?

```
$ node bot.js
Listening on 5000

/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:125
            error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: network does not support ENS (operation="getEnsAddress", info={ "network": { "chainId": "31337", "name": "unknown" } }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.6.0)
    at makeError (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:125:21)
    at assert (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:142:15)
    at EnsResolver.getEnsAddress (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/ens-resolver.js:444:31)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async #getResolver (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/ens-resolver.js:450:25)
    at async EnsResolver.fromName (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/ens-resolver.js:486:26)
    at async WebSocketProvider.getResolver (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/abstract-provider.js:811:16)
    at async WebSocketProvider.resolveName (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/providers/abstract-provider.js:821:26)
    at async Contract.getAddress (/home/code/trading_bot_hardhat-master/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:629:33)
    at async Promise.all (index 0) {
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'getEnsAddress',
  info: { network: Network {} }
}

Node.js v18.12.0
```

Answer (score 1):

99% of the cases that error appears because you are entering an object in a place which expects an address. So probably you use something like `myObject` when you should use something more like `myObject.address()`.

Just check the places where are using addresses (or trying to use). You can also comment out lines until the error disappears and then you have found the erroneous line.